# Why is my mesh blue?

Tags: mesh

I'm new to blender. When I was trying to fix another problem I was clicking things kind of randomly and now I'm stuck with everything being blue. I've seen other people being advised to turn off the show weights in mesh display but if that's the case I don't know where to find it.[image]

Comment: On the top right of your 3D view, click on the Viewport Overlays (double sphere icon) and see if the Face Orientation option is enabled

Comment: Maybe you did some sort of Material Override? What does it show in "Solid" View?

Comment: It was the Face Orientation. Thank you so much!